# DartPad, order of execution, Just In Time?

Tags: dart

I'm new to Dart (from JS) and I'm trying to make sense of this simple program.

When declaring variables and setting then outside in the top part of a program, it seems like (???) the assignment doesn't happen before main() is executed. See below.

```
List<int> a1=[1,2,3];
List<int> b1=new List.from(a1);


void main() {
  a1.add(9);
  print(a1);  // [1,2,3,9]
  print('b1 $b1');  //  CONFUSING   [1,2,3,9]  (I expected [1,2,3])


  List<int> a2=[1,2,3];
  List<int> b2=new List.from(a2);
  a2.add(77);

  print(a2);   // [1,2,3,77]
  print('b2 $b2');  // [1,2,3], as expected
}
```

Is this because there is some Just In Time (JIT) code execution? Or that assignments happen later, like with some JS gotchas.  I did try to read the docs on this but could not figure out anything with code execution order.

I'm most interested in learning how I would learn this myself. So any links to the proper section of the docs is appreciated.

PS. In JS, Chrome Developer Tools gives a handy debugger with breakpoints and I usually use this to check execution order bugs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I confirmed this has the same output using command like dart;  Dart VM version: 2.5.0 (Fri Sep 6 20:10:36 2019 +0200) on "macos_x64"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not JIT, just lazy initialization of global variables.

Dart ensures that no user code runs before the start of `main`. To ensure that, it lazily initializes global and static variables the first time they are read. That does mean that you should be careful when your global variable initializer refers to mutable objects.

Comment: Yes. ***lazy initialization***. Thanks. I wasn't familiar with the term. Once I have the term, this dart gist I found.(https://gist.github.com/hellowmq/eab8a6fdc4b5f34008fa5d07f20f3f28) gives the example too.